# Как сравнить картинки с разными размерами по чексумам, что бы они были одинаковые если на вид одинаковые

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Есть 2 картинки, одна хранится на диске, вторая берется по URL.
Задача в следующем: нужно сравнить эти картинки по чексумам(sha1), на вид они одинаковые, вот только картинка, которая берется через URL имеет немного меньший размер. Проблемма в чем, как мне сравнить их чексумы, так что бы картинки одинаковые, но имеющие разный размер, считались как равные(имели одинаковую чексуму) или это невозможно?
Рассчет чексумы:

```
public static String calculateHashChecksum(URL file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        try (InputStream in = file.openStream()) {
            //Для Файла используется FileInputStream
            generateChecksum(sha1, in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] hashBytes = sha1.digest();
        String fileHash = generateStringHaxChecksum(hashBytes);

        return fileHash;
    }

private static void generateChecksum(MessageDigest sha1, InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 4];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
            sha1.update(data, 0, read);
        }
    }

private static String generateStringHaxChecksum(byte[] hashBytes) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((hashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Возможно. Только контрольную сумму нужно считать не по содержимому файла, а по коэффициентам БПФ

Comment: А вы не могли бы дать ссылку на эти коэфициенты бпф, желательно с примером, спасибо.)